# Any way to get "Employee Details" from Google API?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Is anyone aware of any Google API with the user scope (NOT the Admin API in the Directory SDK) that allows you to retrieve the custom employee attributes?

The G+ API seems to skip these
https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people#resource

Our issue is that we don't want to grant access to the developer console, but rather do this PER-USER. I.E. a user logs into our app and we display to her the custom attributes for her G Suite account, but we do this as her (not as an approved API scope via the dev console).

Comment: May I know what Google API you are using? G+ API or Admin SDK?

Comment: Currently using the +, Gmail, Drive, and Google Cloud Print APIs.  I see that this would be possible using the admin SDK, but then it would have to be set up by the domain admin, and the scope of that is pretty broad for our simple purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving this answer for anyone like me who finds this question.

The Directory API allows a user to query the custom attributes for their account even without any admin permissions at all.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get

You need to ensure that `projection` is set to `full` and `viewType` is set to `domain_public`.

You may need to check the permissions for reading the custom attributes to ensure that a user is allowed to see theirs. We do this in the Google Cloud Directory Sync.

Comment: thanks! is there a way to update externalIds via API?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. In my case, they originate from AD using Google Cloud Directory Sync and I'm pretty sure this is a one-way process.